# Livewire: How to update or re-render when use wire:ignore in <select>

Tags: laravel-livewire, livewires

**Component parent:**

[image]

**Component child**: admin.category.select-recursive
[image]

**-- Problem**: I use recursive for list categories in , I use Modal bootstrap, I use **wire:ignore.self** for component parent, and use **wire.ignore** for , everything showing Ok. I add new data into database from component parent success. But when I re-open modal component parent, I can't see the data just added in . I want re-render or update data just added in . Thanhks you reading. Have a nice day !!!

Answer (score 1):

I had fix success problem.

I add key(time() . rand(0, 999)) in @livewire(...) from component parent

before:

```
@livewire('admin.category.select-recursive',['categories' => $categories,'parent_id' => 0,'icon' => '',])
```

after:

```
@livewire('admin.category.select-recursive',['categories' => $categories,'parent_id' => 0,'icon' => '',],key(time() . rand(0, 999)))
```

Thanhks every one :D